# javascript sort function that returns the keys

Tags: javascript, sorting

Javascript has an inbuilt sort method for arrays.

What I need, is the keys of the array, not the values.  I don't want the array to be modified.
Is there an obvious way to get those keys (before I start writing my own sort...)?

example:

```
var fruit = ["pear", "apple", "lemon"];
fruit.sort();
// now fruit is ["apple", "lemon", "pear"];
```

But what I want to know is

```
keys = [1,2,0] ;
```

So I can use it like this:

```
var fruit = ["pear", "apple", "lemon"]; 
var keys = keysOfSortedArray(fruit);
for(var i in keys) {
  console.log(fruit[key[i]]);
}
```

---

Thanks for helping so fast.  All of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
var fruit = ["pear", "apple", "lemon"];
var sorted = [].concat(fruit).sort();

var sortedIndex = sorted.map(function(item) { 
   return fruit.indexOf(item)
});
console.log(sortedIndex) // prints [1, 2, 0];
```

Comment: `var sortedIndex = sorted.map(item => fruit.indexOf(item));`

Answer (score 1):

You need to take a backup (not deep, shallow backup will do) before sorting

```
var fruit = ["pear", "apple", "lemon"]; 
var backup = fruit.slice();
fruit.sort();
var output = fruit.map(function(val){ return backup.indexOf(val) });
```

Your function `keysOfSortedArray` will be as

```
function keysOfSortedArray(arr)
{
    var backup = arr.slice();
    backup.sort();
    return backup.map(function(val){ return arr.indexOf(val) });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may have a look here: [Sorting with map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Sorting_with_map)

```js
// the array to be sorted
var fruit = ["pear", "apple", "lemon"];

// temporary array holds objects with position and sort-value
var mapped = fruit.map(function (el, i) {
    return { index: i, value: el.toLowerCase() };
})

// sorting the mapped array containing the reduced values
mapped.sort(function (a, b) {
    return +(a.value > b.value) || +(a.value === b.value) - 1;
});

// container for the resulting order
var result = mapped.map(function (el) {
    return fruit[el.index];
});

// get the wanted keys
var keys = mapped.map(function (el) {
    return el.index;
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(keys, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that

Answer (score 0):

This works:

**ES5**

```
function sortIndexes (a) {
    var aClone = a.slice(0);
    return a.sort().map(function(x){
        return aClone.indexOf(x);
    });
}

var fruit = ["pear", "apple", "lemon"];
console.log(sortIndexes(fruit));
```

**Using Prototype** and **ES5**:

```
Array.prototype.sortIndexes = function () {
    var aClone = this.slice(0); 
    return this.sort().map(function (x) {
        return aClone.indexOf(x);
    });
};

var fruit = ["pear", "apple", "lemon"];
console.log(fruit.sortIndexes());
```

**ES6** *(Much beauty)*

```
let sortIndexes = (a) => {
    var aClone = a.slice(0);
    return a.sort().map(x => aClone.indexOf(x));
}


let fruit = ["pear", "apple", "lemon"];
console.log(sortIndexes(fruit));
```

**Using Prototype** and **ES6** (much beauty and better):

```
Array.prototype.sortIndexes = function(){
    let aClone = this.slice(0); 
    return this.sort().map(x => aClone.indexOf(x));
}

let fruit = ["pear", "apple", "lemon"];
console.log(fruit.sortIndexes());
```